# Azure Service Plan CPU is high but web apps use a low CPU

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-plans, azure-webapps

I have an Azure Service Plan and saw the CPU reach 94%:[image]

This Service Plan hosts two web apps, but after checking the availability and performance of the web apps, I didn't see anything abnormal at that time.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas for this case? I don't understand why the Service Plan reports CPU usage of 94% but not any web app consumes CPU.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshots, I think you have selected `Max` as aggregation.
So, it is showing the maximum CPU percentage captured in the overall aggregation interval.

[image]

[image]

you can refer to [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-aggregation-explained#aggregation-types) to know more about aggregation types.

To know about current average CPU percentage of App service plan,
Select Avg as in the Aggregation field, and hover on the current time as shown below.

[image]

**Note:**

- CPU usage can also be caused by the Azure Service Plan itself, not only the web apps hosted on it.
- Even if you stop running web apps, you can still see the CPU, memory consumption by the plan.